# View all http requests when accessing a website [In Code]

Tags: ruby, http, httprequest

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all the http requests that occur when I send a single GET http request via code (ruby in my case).

Basically the same as fiddler or what the NET tab in firebug does.

e.g. when I send a GET request to www.amazon.com firebug says that there are 94 requests for this page. I want to be able to get a list of these 94 requests so that I can use them in my code.

From my knowledge I believe that this would not be possible without using some other type of software such as tcpdump. But to be honest this is out of my depth.

To be clear, I do not want to just use fiddler or firebug as I need to do further data manipulation on the requests within my ruby code.

Comment: Are you using something like Net::HTTP to GET the page?

Comment: If you do a single GET request, there will only be only a single GET request. What you are talking about is when you type the URL in tyour browser and your browser is configured to download a large number of files references in the HTML (css, javascript, images)

Comment: @Jasper That should be an answer instead of a comment, as it is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: @Phrogz I usually keep my answers more about intent than this comment. But since you asked, I resubmitted it as an answer.

Comment: Why do you need more than the first GET?

Comment: Note that some of those requests (XHR) may be due to JavaScript; if you wanted to 'detect' those you would need to have a full web browser within or under the control of Ruby. Do you need those, too?

Comment: It may be possible to do this with Capybara or similar, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to detect all further requests that happen when you type a url in the web browser to view a web page. Hopefully this will make more sense

Answer (score 1):

If you do a single GET request, there will only be only a single GET request.

What you are talking about is when you type the URL in your browser and your browser is configured to download a large number of files references in the HTML (css, javascript, images), which can then be shown in something as Firebug.

I'm afraid you'll have to take another look at just what you are looking for...

Comment: I am looking for how I can get a list of all the http requests that happen when a web browser parses a single web page like you suggested (i.e. css, javascript, images, etc).

Comment: To what degree? Are XHRs (eg AJAX) included? Is using javascript to change an img src? Is the src of an image that is hidden using CSS included? Is it a problem if content is commented out and yet is reported. Should things like frames and links in css be followed?(depth more than a single file)

Comment: What I am trying to say, you are making it sound like a simple thing, but without an actual browser running, it is not.